# Can I use Python and PHP together?

Tags: python, php

I started learning web development, so besides Frontend, which is what I'm learning now, I want to learn a backend language (Python or PHP).

Let's suppose I start learning Python ( or the other way around), but a company that uses PHP for backend hired me.

Is it possible to get along with what I have, or will I have to learn PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI this question is off-topic here, as it's opinion-soliciting. What you choose to learn is entirely up to you. Also, this isn't the place to post career-related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should work, but remember,  treating them as two separate languages because they are PHP and Python, the best approach is to ignore their specificity.